# space between xml tags

Tags: xml, xslt

i need to create empty spaces between xml tags.my input xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EPCISDocument schemaVersion="" creationDate="">
<EPCISHeader>
  <StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
     <HeaderVersion/>
     <Sender>
        <Identifier Authority=""/>
        <ContactInformation>
           <Contact/>
           <EmailAddress/>
           <FaxNumber/>
           <TelephoneNumber/>
           <ContactTypeIdentifier/>
        </ContactInformation>
     </Sender>
     <Receiver>
        <Identifier Authority=""/>
        <ContactInformation>
           <Contact/>
           <EmailAddress/>
           <FaxNumber/>
           <TelephoneNumber/>
           <ContactTypeIdentifier/>
        </ContactInformation>
     </Receiver>
     <DocumentIdentification>
        <Standard/>
        <TypeVersion/>
        <InstanceIdentifier/>
        <Type/>
        <MultipleType/>
        <CreationDateAndTime/>
     </DocumentIdentification>
     <Manifest>
        <NumberOfItems/>
        <ManifestItem>
           <MimeTypeQualifierCode/>
           <UniformResourceIdentifier/>
           <Description/>
           <LanguageCode/>
        </ManifestItem>
     </Manifest>
     <BusinessScope>
        <Scope>
           <BusinessService>
              <BusinessServiceName/>
              <ServiceTransaction TypeOfServiceTransaction=""  IsNonRepudiationRequired="" IsAuthenticationRequired="" IsNonRepudiationOfReceiptRequired="" IsIntegrityCheckRequired="" IsApplicationErrorResponseRequired="" TimeToAcknowledgeReceipt="" TimeToAcknowledgeAcceptance="" TimeToPerform="" Recurrence=""/>
           </BusinessService>
           <CorrelationInformation>
              <RequestingDocumentCreationDateTime/>
              <RequestingDocumentInstanceIdentifier/>
              <ExpectedResponseDateTime/>
           </CorrelationInformation>
        </Scope>
     </BusinessScope>
  </StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
  </EPCISHeader>
  <EPCISBody>
  <EventList>
     <ObjectEvent>
        <eventTime/>
        <recordTime/>
        <eventTimeZoneOffset/>
        <epcList>
           <epc type=""/>
        </epcList>
        <action/>
        <bizStep/>
        <disposition/>
        <readPoint>
           <id/>
        </readPoint>
        <bizLocation>
           <id/>
        </bizLocation>
        <bizTransactionList>
           <bizTransaction type=""/>
        </bizTransactionList>
        <GskEpcExtension>
           <nhrn>  </nhrn>
        </GskEpcExtension>
     </ObjectEvent>
  </EventList>
```

using xslt code i am adding the few prefixes and below is the xslt code

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:epcis="http://apse.com"
  xmlns:sbdh="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader"
  xmlns:gsk="http://epcis.gsk.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EPCISDocument">
     <epcis:EPCISDocument>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </epcis:EPCISDocument>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="GskEpcExtension|GskEpcExtension//*">
    <xsl:element name="gsk:{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="StandardBusinessDocumentHeader|StandardBusinessDocumentHeader//*">
  <xsl:element name="sbdh:{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output my code is coming as expected.but i got new requirement like in the input xml under gskepcextension node one of the field nhrn coming with sapces. but in the ouput xml it is ending like gsk:/nhrn. i need like gsk:nhrn gsk:/nhrn. if value coming in the input for that field it is populating as expected.but when it is coming with space it is not populating as expected.could anyone help on this. for example the output should be like below

```
<gsk:nhrn> </gsk:nhrn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and then you probably want `indent="no"` on the `xsl:output`.

Answer (score 0):

<xsl:preseve-space elements=" mention the name of the elements seperated by space which are required to have empty spaces between tags "/>
<xsl:preseve-space elements="nhrn Contact EmailAddress"/>